# How does the pandas read_csv parse regular expressions, exactly?

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a CSV file with the following structure:

```
word1|word2|word3,word4,0.20,0.20,0.11,0.54,2.70,0.07,1.75
```

That is, a first column of strings (some capitalized, some not) that are separated by '`|`' and by '`,`' (this marks differences in patterns of association) and then 7 digits each separated by ','.

n.b. This dataframe has multiple millions of rows. I have tried to load it as follows:

```
pd.read_csv('pattern_association.csv',sep= ',(?!\D)', engine='python',chunksize=10000)
```

I have followed the advice on here to use a regular expression which aims to capture every column after a digit, but I need one that both selects the first column as a whole string and ignores commas between strings, and then also parses out the 7 columns that are comprised of digits.

How can I get pandas to parse this?

I always get the error.

> Error could possibly be due to quotes being ignored when a
>   multi-char delimiter is used.

I have tried many variations and the regex I am using seems to work outside the context of pandas on toy expressions.

Thanks for any tips.

Comment: The distinction (between | and ,) contains meaningful information.

Comment: It is not clear what the desired output is. Can you add a few lines of sample input with the kind of variation you are expecting and include the desired dataframe you want to get from that input? For example, it is not clear if the number of pipes and commas is always the same.